# how to remove the extra space between letters uitextfield text swift

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextfield

I have uiTextfield called txtCompanyName in viewController. I want to ask how I can prevent user from enter extra space in the between the letters

```
var companyName = txtCompanyName.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range:nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass UITextField and avoid leading spaces as well as double trailing spaces and double spaces between words as follow:

```
class SingleSpaceField: UITextField {
    override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {
        // adds a target to the textfield to monitor when the text changes
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
        // sets the keyboard type to alphabet
        keyboardType = .alphabet
        // set the text alignment to left
        textAlignment = .left
        // sends an editingChanged action to force the textfield to be updated on launch
        sendActions(for: .editingChanged)
    }
    @objc func editingChanged() {
        // this saves the caret position
        let selectedRange = selectedTextRange
        // this avoids leading spaces
        text = text!.replacingOccurrences(of: #"^\s"#, with: "", options: .regularExpression)
        // this avois double spaces anywhere in your field
        text = text!.replacingOccurrences(of: #"\s{2,}"#, with: " ", options: .regularExpression)
        // this restores the caret position
        selectedTextRange = selectedRange
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that spaces " " to be ignored while input, you should use one of UITextFieldDelegate method:

```
  func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = textField.text else {
      return false
    }
    if text == " " {
      return false
    }
    return true
  }
```

Hope you get the idea and this helps.

Comment: `guard let text = textField.text else` will never fail. UITextField default value is an empty string

Comment: @LeoDabus we can't always be sure..)) But, this actually for removing optionality mostly. In other hand we may use something like - let currentText = textField.text ?? ""

Comment: Even if you assign nil to it and get its value on the next line it will return an empty string. You can simply force unwrap the result `text!`